# How to add an additional channel to existing pre-trained resnet50 model in tesorflow_hub?

Tags: tensorflow, resnet, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to use pre-trained Resnet50 model from tensorflow_hub. However, I intend to modify the first convolution layer to be able to take a 4-channel tensor(image+binary mask), where the network weights are initialized from the pre-trained model, except for the newly
added filters which are initialized randomly.

Basic code used to extract Resnet50 weights:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/feature_vector/3")
batch = 2
channels = 3
height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module)
images = np.zeros((batch, height, width, channels))
features = module(dict(images=images), signature="image_feature_vector", as_dict=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the network architecture like that, it may be best to work with TensorFlow source code directly. There are several implementations of ResNet-50 for TensorFlow, including (in no particular order)

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras/applications (easy to use with Keras and TF2)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official (carefully benchmarked)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets (not TF2-compliant per se, but the source of the Hub module you're using)

See the respective repositories for instructions on restoring a pre-trained checkpoint. (Moving off Hub modules, you'll lose that nice automation.)